# Sqoop: double quotes query

Tags: sql, sqoop, double-quotes

I have a problem with the double quotes on this sqoop query:

```
select i.Number, i.Date,i.Station, i.lStation, 
count(*) ax, “1- Pd” St  , b.Type 
from Leg jl, yLeg i, senger b, 
where jl.LegID = i.LegID and jl.rID = b.erID and b.gID = b.ID  
and b.tus not in (1,4) group by Number, Date, tion, b.Type
```

how can i fixed? with some escape parameter

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes '' ?

Comment: you have a extra `,` in the `from` clause

Comment: it's and example, the real problem is the “1- Pd” St. On the other hand i tried with '1- Pd' St , '“1- Pd”' St, “'1- Pd'” St all the combination with the quotes

Comment: what is that 1- Pd ? is Pd a column name? i didn't understand your query first.? 'count(*) ax, “1- Pd” St ' specially this part.

Answer (score 1):

First debug the query with the below command `sqoop eval -libjars /var/lib/sqoop/ojdbc6.jar --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:portnumber/servicename --username user -password password --query "select * from schemaname.tablename where rownum=10"` write your query in the --query and see if the actual query is generating the output you are expecting ? you can see the output in the terminal itself.

If the query is giving the results as you expected, use the below sqoop command
to import the table

```
sqoop import -libjars /var/lib/sqoop/ojdbc6.jar --connect 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname/service_name' --username user -password password -m 1 --hive-overwrite --hive-import --hive-database database_name --hive-table table_nmae --target-dir '/user/hive/warehouse/databasename.db/tablename' --query "select * from source_database.source_tablename WHERE 1=1 AND \$CONDITIONS"
```

The exact problem with the double quotes you are facing can be resolved using escape key. Please us the **WHERE 1=1 AND \$CONDITIONS** as is and paste your query before the **WHERE** in sqoop command.

If you face any error please paste the error, you must need to add an other escape key to escape the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this question.

The first is what is a valid query for your source database?  Most databases have some kind of client or shell that let you enter and execute queries.  Your query should be valid as far as the shell or client is concerned.

The second part of your question is how do you take that query (as a String) and pass it to the database via sqoop. The answer to that lies in the way you're running sqoop.

If you're running sqoop via command line then you need to identify those characters (usually double quotes) that give your OS fits when embedded in a command line argument.  Use a backslash before those characters to help the OS parse the command correctly.  You usually have to put the entire query string inside unescaped double quotes so that the OS treats your query as a single string argument.

If you're running sqoop via Oozie then I strongly recommend you break the Sqoop command into arguments in the Sqoop action:

```
<arg>--query</arg>
<arg>select ... count(*) ax, “1- Pd” St  , b.Type ...  WHERE $CONDITIONS</arg>
```

So that you can generally paste your query as is into the action.

Of course, nothing is that simple.  You still have to remember that the query is sitting inside an XML document, so any character that will mess up an XML parse become problematic.  The only characters like that that I've encountered so far are the angle brackets and I use property substitution (a bit of a kludge, I admit) to solve that problem:

In the Oozie workflow properties file I put:

```
lessThan=<
```

and I change my arg from

```
<arg>SELECT * from MyTable where $CONDITIONS AND (SOME_COL < 1000)</arg>
```

to

```
<arg>SELECT * from MyTable where $CONDITIONS AND (SOME_COL ${lessThan} 1000)</arg>
```

EDIT:

For those of you who don't like my kludge, you could try using a CDATA element to "escape" anything in the query (except, of course, ']]>'):

```
<arg><![CDATA[SELECT * from MyTable where $CONDITIONS AND (SOME_COL < 1000)]]></arg>
```